# How does Browser interpret CSS and how is it processed?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, webbrowser-control

I am using IE 7 and want to know:

1. how does any browser understand and process CSS.
2. Is it possible to handle it by using some framework
3. Is it possible to create framework in JavaScript so as to implement all the CSS3 styling in browsers such as IE6 or IE 7

   I want to deal with this because most of the programming done in my industry should be compatible with IE6 and IE7 and I am fedup of using Images and want to add life to the pages using CSS3. 
   So can anyone suggest me some good way to get along ??

Comment: You mean your company? I doubt that there exists an entire industry which requires compatibility with IE6...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Mine does. Its actually not the company but the customers and the users who dont want to change the browser. Company provides compatibility with all the browsers but IE sucks and I have to look into it specifically :(

Answer (score 2):

Try [:select[ivizr]](http://selectivizr.com/), for CSS3 selectors in IE 6-8.
As for `border-radius` in IE6-8, [use this hack](http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Is depending on the browser and its version. Most browsers will create NEWER versions when a new MAJOR version of CSS or HTML is developed (even before [if ever] final).
2. <strike>Most likely it will not be possible since this means you will need to update an older browser to support styles that may not have been available at the time of release</strike>.. see comment from naveen
3. If 2 would be possible I do not see why it shouldn't be doable in a javascript kind of way.... 
   --- Look someone already did it- See comment from naveen

I so not see where "Fedup of using Images" and CSS3 come together, but please feel free to explain further